# Querying SQL Server from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, collation

I've been searching this topic, but haven´t found any solution; there was a similar question, but it is not solved: [Working with characters with accents in sql query and table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910354/working-with-characters-with-accents-in-sql-query-and-table-name)

I'm working with a database on a SQL Server 2005 that uses Modern_Spanish_CI_AS as collation. I'm developing a web front-end using PHP, and I am stuck with an accent problem.

There's a table (let's say "Objetos") whose fields are: ID Name **Descripción**

I can´t query this table because of the accent. If I build my query `"Select a.ID, a.Name FROM Objetos"` it works perfect, but if changed into `"Select a.ID, a.Descripción FROM Objetos"` it returns zero rows.

I can´t change the collation of the database, so I have been decoding the queries before sending them `$ssql = utf8_decode($ssql);`... It is strange, using this workaround I can do `INSERT`, but cant `SELECT`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If you want to live a happy life, always use only use standard ascii chars for table and field definitions.

Comment: As user247245 said, you will have a hell of a rough ride if you use anything but lower ansi characters for table/column names. You should follow the same rule as in any other language: Entitie names MUST not contain special characters.

In addition to that. You should ALLWAYS use utf8_general_ci or one of it's sisters for all your databases and tables. This collation contains any and all special chars and can easily used in any programming code.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the column with the "`" character.  If it doesn't work, try removing the "a." prefix from the column name.